# C# reflection loop through methods and give unique names only (ignoring overloaded)

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm using the following to loop through all static methods in a class but there are a number of overloaded methods. I only want unique names so for example if there are 3 overloaded methods named "Run()", then I only want 1 returned in my query and not 3. For now I don't care that there are overloaded methods. Is there a way I can filter this on the query instead of after? The class has like 600+ static methods (it's a binding from another library from a DLL) and if I can limit the unique names up front it should help make my load faster. I'm basically taking the names and populating a menu with the names.

MethodInfo[] leMethods = typeof(MyType).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't believe there's any way of doing it *in the `GetMethods` call* but it's easy to do afterwards with LINQ:

```
var methodNames = typeof(MyType).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public |
                                            BindingFlags.Static)
                                .Select(x => x.Name)
                                .Distinct()
                                .OrderBy(x => x);
```

Note that I've put the ordering at the very end, so there's less to sort - and because we're only getting the name anyway, we're just performing the natural ordering.

Comment: Very nice, thank you very much. How can I order by the Name property then? I need to get more familiar with linq. I know SQL and just wish it was exactly like SQL :)

Comment: So I modified it slightly to get MethodInfo returned instead of just the name, but when I try to loop through it with foreach I get and error saying "At least one object must implement IComparable.". How can I modify this so it returns a list of MethodInfo instead of string?

Comment: @user441521: At that point it becomes a bit of a pain to get distinct elements. You could use DistinctBy from MoreLINQ if you like though - http://morelinq.googlecode.com, and use `.DistinctBy(x => x.Name)`.

Comment: I'll give that a try. If I just wanted to test syntax without the distinct I try the following and it gives me that "must implement IComparable" error:


var methodNames = typeof(LeadwerksEngine.LE).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
                                .Select(x => x)
                                .OrderBy(x => x);
            foreach (MethodInfo mi in methodNames)
            {

Comment: @user441521: Without the distinct, you can get rid of the `Select`, but you need to change the `OrderBy` to `OrderBy(x => x.Name)`. But it's worth learning about LINQ properly, not just by copying examples. It's an incredibly powerful technology.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! Yeah, I have to read up on linq more as the syntax confuses me. This all worked and got me to what I was needing so thanks again.